# How could I detect when a directory is mounted with inotify?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, inotify

I'm using Linux Inotify to detect FS events on my program.

How could I be notified when a device is mounted on a monitored directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `inotify`. Here is the method though:

1. Read [uevents from kernel](http://lwn.net/Articles/242046/) via a [Netlink](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/netlink.7.html) socket and filter out those where `"ACTION"` is not `"mount"`.
2. [Read and parse `"/proc/mounts"`](http://kerneltrap.org/man/linux/man3/getmntent_r.3) when you get an event with a `"mount"` action.
3. Find a record for a mount point with device that was just mounted and filter it out if it's not the directory you are watching.

Comment: The alternative is to put an `inotify` watch on `/etc/mtab`, and do the same kind of parsing as you would do on `/proc/mounts`.  But this is much more fragile.

Comment: I'm not sure there are any `mount` actions from `uevent` in the kernel now. It seems that it was [considered broken, and removed](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/2/22/169).

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Update to be less than 5 years obsolete

If you're on anything but the most ancient of systems, [libudev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/index.html) is what you want for the first step.

If you're on something from this decade, [udisks](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/) will do all of this for you, too. You'd need to watch the [org.Freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-objectmanager) interface on [/org/freedesktop/UDisks2](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/ref-dbus-udisks2-well-known-object.html) to see when new [filesystems](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem.html) turn up.

Answer (score 2):

On modern Linux systems /etc/mtab often points to /proc/self/mounts:

`$ ls -l /etc/mtab
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Sep  5  2013 /etc/mtab -> /proc/mounts
$ ls -l /proc/mounts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Jul 10 14:56 /proc/mounts -> self/mounts`

proc(5) [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) says that you don't really need to use inotify for this file, it is pollable:

> Since kernel version 2.6.15, this
>                 file is pollable: after opening the file for reading, a change
>                 in this file (i.e., a filesystem mount or unmount) causes
>                 select(2) to mark the file descriptor as readable, and poll(2)
>                 and epoll_wait(2) mark the file as having an error condition.

Was wondered why inotify not works on /etc/mtab and found this manpage.

Answer (score 2):

inotify only tells you about unmounts, and uevents no longer tells you about mount/unmount.

The way to do is to poll on /proc/mounts, read in the contents, and keep track of the mounts you've seen, and then reparse when the poll wakes up. The poll will wake up on ERR/PRI when any filesystem is mounted or unmounted.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    struct pollfd ev;
    int ret;
    ssize_t bytesread;
    char buf[8192];

    fd = open("/proc/mounts", O_RDONLY);
    printf("########################################\n");
    while ((bytesread = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
        write(1, buf, bytesread);

    do {

        ev.events = POLLERR | POLLPRI;
        ev.fd = fd;
        ev.revents = 0;
        ret = poll(&ev, 1, -1);
        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        if (ev.revents & POLLERR) {
            printf("########################################\n");
            while ((bytesread = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
                write(1, buf, bytesread);
        }
    } while (ret >= 0);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code just prints out the mount points on startup, and then on any mount/unmount. It's up to you to "diff" them to find out what got added/removed.

Note, all these techniques has been both unstable and/or broken in past Linux versions. It all got stable around the end of Linux 2.6.35 (or maybe a bit earlier).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind *lots* of false alarms, you might be able to watch for `close_nowrite` on `/etc/fstab`. . Watching `/etc/mtab`, `/proc/mounts`, etc. doesn't work for me.