# How to get event when an FS is mount

Tags: linux, events, linux-kernel, mount, inotify

I need to catch the mount event on a certain mount point.
I don't know if a try with inotify is feasible.
Is it possible? How?

Best regards
Max

Comment: You probably want to look up `dbus`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I detect when a directory is mounted with inotify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113176/how-could-i-detect-when-a-directory-is-mounted-with-inotify)